# Zip structure created by Gradle Application Plugin

Tags: plugins, gradle

I would like to change folder structure of zip created by gradle application plugin.
For example instead of "test.zip -> test -> bin" i would like to have "test.zip -> bin".

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "asdasd"
applicationName = "test"
```

I have tried to somehow modify "into" but it failed. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Have you ruled out using the gradle zip task?  Is there a reason you want to use the application plugin?

Comment: I thought about it, but i need to create start scripts and jar. Application plugin meets my requirements

Comment: I know that i can use other tasks, but as i said this plugin meets my requirements. I would like to configure structure of zip.